# My program only outputs a highestElement of 1

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code:

```
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int highestElement(int [], int);
void doubleArray(int [], int);
void showValues(int [], int);

int main()
{

   const int ARRAY_SIZE = 7;
   int set[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

   // Display the initial values.
   cout << "The arrays values are:\n";
   showValues(set, ARRAY_SIZE);

   // Double the values in the array.
   doubleArray(set, ARRAY_SIZE);

   // Display the resulting values.
   cout << "After calling doubleArray the values are:\n";
   showValues(set, ARRAY_SIZE);


   cout << "The highest element in the array is " << highestElement << endl;

   return 0;
}

//*****************************************************
// Definition of function doubleArray                 *
// This function doubles the value of each element    *
// in the array passed into nums. The value passed    *
// into size is the number of elements in the array.  *
//*****************************************************

void doubleArray(int nums[], int size)
{
   for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
      nums[index] *= 2;
}

//**************************************************
// Definition of function showValues.              *
// This function accepts an array of integers and  *
// the array's size as its arguments. The contents *
// of the array are displayed.                     * 
//**************************************************

void showValues(int nums[], int size)
{
   for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
      cout << nums[index] << " ";
   cout << endl;
}

// Definition of highestElement (what I need help fixing)

int highestElement(int numbers [], int size)
{
   int count;
   int highest;
   highest = numbers[0];
   for (count = 1; count < size; count++)
   {
      if (numbers[count] < highest)
      {
      highest = numbers[count];
      }
   }
}
```

My errors:

```
main.cpp:29:54: warning: the address of ‘int highestElement(int*, int)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
    cout << "The highest element in the array is " << highestElement << endl;
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int highestElement(int*, int)’:
main.cpp:75:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

My output is:

```
The arrays values are:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
After calling doubleArray the values are:
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 
The highest element in the array is 1
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, the highestElement always equals 1. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I haven't been able to solve it on my own. I'm trying to make the highest element of the array be outputted. I sincerely await a helpful reply.

Comment: Rather than spam the reader with pseudo-latin, can you explain what about the warning message you find confusion? It’s telling you that you aren’t calling the function at all, merely getting its address. You also don’t return anything when you should.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to pass the arguments as declared for the function `highestElement`.

```
cout << "The highest element in the array is " << highestElement(set, ARRAY_SIZE) << endl;
```

Second, since you are looking for max in the array you need to check if current element is `greater` than older:

```
if (numbers[count] > highest)
{
  highest = numbers[count];
}
```

Third, you need to `return highest` from the function `highestElement()` to the main caller.

```
return highest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function `highestElement` with the correct arguments.

The line:

```
    cout << "The highest element in the array is " << highestElement << endl;
```

should change to:

```
    cout << "The highest element in the array is " << highestElement(set, ARRAY_SIZE) << endl;
```

Also the implmentation of `highestElement` should return the highest value

And the check should be for greater instead of smaller

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function `highestElement()`, so it is giving above errors.
It should be like :

```
cout << "The highest element in the array is " << highestElement(set, ARRAY_SIZE) << endl;
```

This is also pointed out by the Error Message

> warning: the **address** of ‘int highestElement(int*, int)’ will always
>   evaluate as ‘true’

Your code is not calling the function and using the return value, but instead is printing the pointer to the function.